# how to get zoho editor in AjaXplorer?

Tags: editor, zoho, pydio

I have a simple problem in using the zoho editor. I need to be able to open any file type with ajaxplorer zoho text editor (ex: .docx files,).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer..just enable "Yes" in settings/plugin/editor/zoho editor...;-)